# Как правильно изменять данные в своем JSON сервере?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Разрабатываю небольшой интернет магазин на react/redux. Использую свой JSON сервер.
Реализован функционал по добавлению товаров в корзину. Я беру нужный товар и с помощью метода POST пушу данные в специальный массив в JSON файле:

```
  "shoppingcard": [
  {
    "img": "https://cdn.sela.ru/wa-data/public/shop/products/81/76/117681/images/157525/157525.2250x3000.jpg",
    "price": "1000",
    "descr": "блузка женская классная",
    "color": "синий",
    "size": "S",
    "id": "123231",
    "count": "1",
    "totalPrice": "1000",
    "more": "Тут будет красочное описание данной вещи"
  }
]
```

Далее в компоненте "КОРЗИНА" я методом GET получаю эти данные и отображаю на странице. Так же уже в самой корзине реализован функционал по увеличению и по уменьшению количества товара

```
    case 'INCREASE_COUNT' :
        return {
            ...state,
            shoppingcard: state.shoppingcard.map(item => {
                if (item.id === action.payload) {
                    return {
                        ...item,
                        count: +item.count + 1,
                        totalPrice: (+item.count + 1) * item.price
                    }
                }
                return item;
            })
        }
```

Получается я меняю стейт, все корректно работает, но данные(количество товара) в JSON файле какими были, такими и остаются,что понятно. Но предположим пользователь в корзине увеличил количество товара и нажал купить. Абстрактный бэкенд об этом не узнает. И собственно вопрос: как мне правильно изменить определенный параметр массива в JSONе при изменении этого параметра уже внутри корзины,когда данные туда загружены? Опытные люди подскажите как это вообще чаще всего реализовывается в связке с бэком?

Comment: Как обычно реализуется:
Конечно вы можете хранить все корзины всех пользователей на бэкенде, но это явно скажется на эффективности вашего сервера. Очень часто хранение информации о корзине хранится на самом клиенте в localStorage. Так например работает корзина на Yandex Market. 

Что вам нужно изменить:
Т.к. вы используете redux вы можете попробовать библиотеку redux-persist для добавления вашего store в localStorage или другое хранилище.
При такой реализации объекты в массиве shoppingcard не должны содержать такие поля как price(цена), потому, что user сможет отредактировать эти данные

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, тогда у меня есть несколько тупых вопросов новичка, уж не обессудьте. Если я вас правильно понял, мне вообще не нужно в своем JSON файле создавать массив для хранения корзины, а просто сохранять его в localStorage и потом бэкенд каким-то образом забирает от туда данные и обрабатывает?

Comment: Я бы не сказал что бэкенд будет именно забирать данные, скорее это пользователь при завершении покупки будет отправлять данные о товарах находящихся в корзине. А так да вы всё правильно поняли.